# Sockets with Silverlight application?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, sockets, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to use sockets with a Silverlight Application, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code so far:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
...
...
Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 0));
server.Listen(1);
```

But I get an error message saying that `Bind` and `Listen` are not defined. Does anyone know why this might be?

I using Silverlight 4, with .NET 4.0 (visual studio 2010).

Answer (score 4):

The code you have provided is .Net and not Silverlight. There is a big difference between the two as .Net support both synchronous and asynchronous data transfers while silverlight only supports asynchronous mode. Check out the difference on msdn:

- [Sockets for Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Sockets for .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx)

The links also have examples on how to use them.

Comment: Yes it is .NET code. Could you give me the Silverlight equivalent please.

Comment: @Rodger here in SO we do not give code like that, we give hints, suggestions and ideas but not complete out of the box solutions. You can document yourself about the differences reading at the above links, you try something out and if you have issues you post your code and ask for help. Nobody will find the time or do the effort to write the whole code for you. unless you then devote your salary to him :D

Answer (score 0):

I would use a WCF endpoint on the server which does this communication ( and again, via WCF instead of sockets if possible ), then the SL UI would simply communicate with the ECF endpoint async....

Comment: I dont understand, could you give an example please.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight does not allow creation of server sockets. You can only open client sockets and connect to a server.